# Writing XML to a file without overwriting previous data (VB.net)

Tags: xml, vb.net

I'm trying to do a sub routine that every time is called adds a new entry of data to the XML file, but at the moment the only thing it does is overwriting the data.

This is the code I'm using

```
 Dim fabpath As String = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "Fabricantes.xml")

        Dim xmlDoc As New XmlDocument()
        Dim docNode As XmlNode
        Dim fabricantes As XmlNode
        Dim docElement As XmlElement

        docNode = xmlDoc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", Nothing)
        xmlDoc.AppendChild(docNode)

        fabricantes = xmlDoc.CreateElement("Fabricantes")
        xmlDoc.AppendChild(fabricantes)

        docElement = xmlDoc.CreateElement("Nome_do_Fabricante")
        docElement.InnerText = fabric.Name
        fabricantes.AppendChild(docElement)

        xmlDoc.Save(fabpath)
```

And the result I'm expecting in the XML file is something like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Fabricantes>
    <Nome_do_Fabricante>xxxxxx</Nome_do_Fabricante>
    <Nome_do_Fabricante>xxxxxx</Nome_do_Fabricante>
    <Nome_do_Fabricante>xxxxxx</Nome_do_Fabricante>
    .
    .
    .
    <Nome_do_Fabricante>xxxxxx</Nome_do_Fabricante>
</Fabricantes>
```

Comment: You should load the current XML document from the file, modify it, and then write it back to the file on disk.

Comment: As an aside, you might find it easier to work with the XML classes in `System.Xml.Linq` than the original `XmlDocument` etc. which were basically written against .NET 1.0 (thus everything is `Object`, no generics, etc.).

Comment: Thank you for the answers, with all the info i was able to resolve the problem

Answer (score 0):

In your example, you are creating a new file and saving it over the existing file every time. It sounds like you want to load the existing file, add to it, and then save the changes.

If that is the case, then look at this example that does just that:

```vb
Private Sub ModifyXml(path As String, nomeDoFabricante As String)
    Dim xmlDoc As New XmlDocument()
    xmlDoc.Load(path)

    Dim fabricantes = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//Fabricantes")
    If (fabricantes Is Nothing) Then
        fabricantes = xmlDoc.CreateElement("Fabricantes")
        xmlDoc.AppendChild(fabricantes)
    End If

    Dim appendingElement = xmlDoc.CreateElement("Nome_do_Fabricante")
    docElement.InnerText = nomeDoFabricante
    fabricantes.Append(appendingElement)

    xmlDoc.Save(path)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

As Andrew said; load, add, and write.

**Asumming  you only want one Fabricantes node**

```
    Dim fabpath As String = IO.Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "Fabricantes.xml")

    Dim xmlDoc As XElement = XElement.Load(fabpath) '  LOAD

    Dim newEL As XElement
    If xmlDoc Is Nothing OrElse xmlDoc.Name.LocalName <> "Fabricantes" Then
        newEL = <Fabricantes>
                    <Nome_do_Fabricante><%= fabric.Name %></Nome_do_Fabricante>
                </Fabricantes>
        xmlDoc.AddFirst(newEL)
    Else
        newEL = <Nome_do_Fabricante><%= fabric.Name %></Nome_do_Fabricante>
        xmlDoc.Add(newEL) '  ADD NEW
    End If

    xmlDoc.Save(fabpath) '  SAVE
```

Comment: The document could be `XDocument` instead of `XElement` I think.